# Allowing a Form to Accept Cmd line arguments

Tags: c++, winforms, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have an application that now has a settings file that can be loaded. One desired functionality I wish to give the user is the ability to double click the specific file type I have created and have the application open the file.

To my understanding this means that when a user double clicks the application, the file that was double-clicked has its full path passed to my application as a cmdline argument.

In order to load this file I have attempted to do the following in my Form1.cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <windows.h>
//Command Line Args
#include <shellapi.h>

using namespace JohnDeereDataqGUI;

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
{
System::Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->ApartmentState = System::Threading::ApartmentState::STA;
int argCount;
LPWSTR * argList;
argList = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argCount);
Application::Run(new Form1(argList[0]));
LocalFree(argList);
return 0;
}
```

And for my constructor:

```
public:
    Form1(String * argument)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(argument)
            loadPreviousSettings((const char *)(void*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(argument));
    }
```

Currently, the file does not load when I double click the files of my specified type. My application loads, but the settings are set to the defaults instead of the custom settings stored in the file that was supposed to be loaded. Also I am having issues trying to debug this since, I can't run the application in debug mode and then double-click a file on the computer since it starts up a seperate .exe that will not hit breakpoints of course.

I would like to know what the issue might be and/or if there is an easier way to do this.

#### Note:

I am writing this in Visual Studio 2003, so some actions that work in later versions may not be possible for me.

Comment: You can debug it by setting its command line and working directory in the Visual Studio Debugger settings for the project.  Or put a `Sleep` in at the start of `_tWinMain` and then attach the debugger to it.

Comment: Thanks, I just passed in the argument using the command line option in the debugger settings and saw that it was the second argument that I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to passs argument[1] instead of argument[0], since [0] is the path to the application of course and [1] is the file I am passing. Simple mistake.

Final Solution:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <windows.h>
//Command Line Args
#include <shellapi.h>

using namespace JohnDeereDataqGUI;

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
{
System::Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->ApartmentState = System::Threading::ApartmentState::STA;
int argCount;
LPWSTR * argList;
argList = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argCount);
if( argCount > 1)
    Application::Run(new Form1(argList[1]));
else
    Application::Run(new Form1());
LocalFree(argList);
return 0;
 }
```

And:

```
 Form1(String * argument)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(argument)
            loadPreviousSettings((const char *)(void*)     System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(argument));
    }
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```